# Freeze column or rows after 24 hour automatically

Tags: excel, vba

I want to freeze column or row (whichever is possible) based on time zone. It means i want to freeze column or row automatically against particular date once day changes from 1jan to 2jan and so on.

sample data is as follow [data entered (rows or column) are freezed becoz that day is crossed and next day is open]. (difficult to add image as i need 10 points to do that.)

Please suggest.

Thanks.

Sample data is as follows:

date        abc123            def223     ad                df
30/06/2014  hello             on leave   hi             (forget to enter)
1/7/2014    (forget to enter)   hi     (forget to enter)    do
2/7/2014
3/7/2014

or

date    30/06/2014          1/7/2014          2/7/2014  3/7/2014
abc123  hello             (forget to enter)
def223  on leave            hi
ad      hi                 (forget to enter)
df      (forget to enter)   do

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because you have not tried anything yourself.  This is not doyourhomeworkoverflow.

Comment: Lack of effort to solve this yourself aside, are you asking about locking a column or row, or freezing panes at a column or row?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Test()

Dim Tdate As Date
Dim DateRow As Long, FCol As Long

Tdate = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy")

DateRow = 3 'Number that your dates are on (in row)

FCol = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(DateRow, 1).EntireRow.Find(What:=Tdate, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Column

Columns(FCol).Offset(0, 1).Select

ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

End Sub
```

This will search the row that you specify (`Tdate`) for today's date. If found, it will freeze the pane so that that column is the last column included in the freezepane. Please beaware that this will keep all things left frozen aswell. Not ideal if your doing day to day additions as you'll end up with all the previous days in the freeze pane too. But this is all I could get from your question.

Please edit and use as you like

Comment: plz give ur mail id if u can, i will send u image for clarification, as that only i can do.

Comment: Sorry, but what I've provided may not work in its **exact** format, but you can at least maked an attempt to adapt it, use bits of it and update your answer. I'm not going to sit here re-writing it until it fits your exact requirements without any attempt on your behalf. That's not how SO works!